# keyerror 1 in my code

Tags: python, keyerror

I am writing a function that take dictionary input and return list of keys which have unique values in that dictionary. Consider,

```
ip = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3}
```

so output should be [3] as key 3 has unique value which is not present in dict.

Now there is problem in given fuction:

```
def uniqueValues(aDict):

    dicta = aDict
    dum = 0
    for key in aDict.keys():

        for key1 in aDict.keys():

            if key == key1:
                dum = 0
            else:
                if aDict[key] == aDict[key1]:
                    if key in dicta:
                        dicta.pop(key)
                    if key1 in dicta:
                        dicta.pop(key1)

    listop = dicta.keys()
    print listop
    return listop
```

I am getting error like:

> File "main.py", line 14, in uniqueValues
>       if aDict[key] == aDict[key1]: KeyError: 1

Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: You are modifying your dictionary (`dicta.pop(key)`) while iterating through it which causes unexpected result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your main problem is this line:

```
dicta = aDict
```

You think you're making a copy of the dictionary, but actually you still have just one dictionary, so operations on dicta also change aDict (and so, you remove values from adict, they also get removed from aDict, and so you get your KeyError).

One solution would be

```
dicta = aDict.copy()
```

(You should also give your variables clearer names to make it more obvious to yourself what you're doing)

(edit) Also, an easier way of doing what you're doing:

```
def iter_unique_keys(d):
    values = list(d.values())
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if values.count(value) == 1:
            yield key

print list(iter_unique_keys({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Counter`** from `collections` library:

```
from collections import Counter

ip = {
    1: 1,
    2: 1,
    3: 3,
    4: 5,
    5: 1,
    6: 1,
    7: 9
}

# Generate a dict with the amount of occurrences of each value in 'ip' dict
count = Counter([x for x in ip.values()])

# For each item (key,value) in ip dict, we check if the amount of occurrences of its value.
# We add it to the 'results' list only if the amount of occurrences equals to 1. 
results = [x for x,y in ip.items() if count[y] == 1]

# Finally, print the results list
print results
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 7]
```

Comment: This is a good way to perform what OP is trying to do, but this does not actually help him to understand why its code was failing.

Comment: @Delgan, I won't fix his code. It's better to educate people than to just show them workarounds. If he gets an answer to solve his issue, will someone else be benefited from that answer? Do you want to help him or the whole community? Think beyond the box, this a community.

Comment: If you do not help him understanding what was wrong with is code i.e. `dicta = aDict` is not performing a real copy, then he will make the same mistake in the future, and ask the same kind of question again. This is not just showing workarounds, this is explaining and educating. This also help others people which are not aware of this issue. Providing an alternative and a most elegant way to perform what he is trying to do is very nice, but this should not be the lonely part of your answer, it should be wrote in addition.

Comment: Why should I post an additional answer while the one of Emile perfectly explains the issue and provides an alternative way to do the job?...